# How the rating bar could keep the last votes

Tags: java, android, ratingbar

A list view includes different names. When i choose one name, opens a new window which contains details and a rating bar. Every user can vote in rating bar.There is also and a text view that shows how many ratings have been done. 
Everything is working until here.

When i go back in the list view and choose again a name from the list, the rating bar and the text view is in a default mode.

Can anyone help me with that issue??

Comment: you have to store the value of rating in a variable

Comment: From where are you retrieving those names?